# Objectify throws IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.app.db.client.model.ProductType' was registered

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, objectify

I am using Objectify 5.1.7 with [Objectify Spring extension](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Extensions#spring.) in my Spring-MVC application.

Here are my entity classes:

Product.java

```
@Entity
public class Product extends RelatedDataObject {

@Parent
private Ref<Vendor> vendor;
@Load
private Ref<ProductCategory> productCategory;
@Load
private Ref<ProductType> productType;

@Index
private String nativeId;
private Double costPrice;
private String modelId;
private String serviceLocations;
private Map<String, String> attributes;

public Double getCostPrice() {
    return costPrice;
}

public String getModelId() {
    return modelId;
}

public String getServiceLocations() {
    return serviceLocations;
}

public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
    return attributes;
}

public void setCostPrice(Double costPrice) {
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
}

public void setModelId(String modelId) {
    this.modelId = modelId;
}

public void setServiceLocations(String serviceLocations) {
    this.serviceLocations = serviceLocations;
}

public void setAttributes(Map<String, String> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}

public void addAttribute(String key, String value) {
    if(key == null || value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key or value is null.");
    }
    if(attributes == null) {
        attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    attributes.put(key, value);
}

public ProductCategory getProductCategory() {
    return productCategory.get();
}

public ProductType getProductType() {
    return productType.get();
}

public String getNativeId() {
    return nativeId;
}

public void setNativeId(String nativeId) {
    this.nativeId = nativeId;
}

public void setProductCategory(ProductCategory productCategory) {
    this.productCategory = Ref.create(productCategory);
}

public void setProductType(ProductType productType) {
    this.productType = Ref.create(productType);
}

public Vendor getVendor() {
    return vendor.get();
}

public void setVendor(Vendor vendor) {
    this.vendor = Ref.create(vendor);
}



public Key<Product> getKeyByParentVendor() {

    if (getId() == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product id is not set.");
    }
    if (vendor == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parent vendor is not set.");
    }

    return Key.create(this.vendor.key(), Product.class, getId());

   }
}
```

ProductType.java

```
@Entity
public class ProductType extends RelatedDataObject {
}
```

RelatedDataObject.java

```
public class RelatedDataObject extends DataObject {

private String description;
private boolean approved;

public RelatedDataObject() {
    super();
    approved = false;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public boolean isApproved() {
    return approved;
}

public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
    this.approved = approved;
}
}
```

DataObject.java

```
public class DataObject {

@Id
private String id;
@Index
private String name;
private boolean inactive;

public DataObject() {
    super();
    inactive = false;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public boolean isInactive() {
    return inactive;
}

public void setInactive(boolean inactive) {
    this.inactive = inactive;
}
}
```

And here is my spring bean xml configuration. All my entity classes are inside the package: com.app.db.client.client.model

```
<bean id="objectifyFactory" class="com.googlecode.objectify.spring.ObjectifyFactoryBean">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.app.db.client.model"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dbClient" class="com.app.db.client.impl.DbClientImpl">
    <property name="objectifyFactory" ref="objectifyFactory"/>
</bean>
```

DBClientImpl.java

```
public class DbClientImpl implements DbClient {

private ObjectifyFactory objectifyFactory;

public void setObjectifyFactory(ObjectifyFactory objectifyFactory) {
    this.objectifyFactory = objectifyFactory;
}

@Override
public <T extends DataObject> void createObject(T object) {

    Objectify ofy = objectifyFactory.begin();
    ofy.save().entity(object).now();
}
}
```

When the GAE devserver boots my spring MVC application, all entity classes are loaded. Here are the log messages:

```
[INFO] 2015-09-10 13:20:15 INFO  ObjectifyFactoryBean:115 - Registered entity class [com.app.db.client.model.Product]
[INFO] 2015-09-10 13:20:15 INFO  ObjectifyFactoryBean:115 - Registered entity class [com.app.db.client.model.ProductCategory]
[INFO] 2015-09-10 13:20:15 INFO  ObjectifyFactoryBean:115 - Registered entity class [com.app.db.client.model.ProductType]
[INFO] 2015-09-10 13:20:15 INFO  ObjectifyFactoryBean:115 - Registered entity class [com.app.db.client.model.Vendor]
```

When I try to save Product entity:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.setName("new product");
product.setProductType(productType);
product.setProductCategory(productCategory);
product.setNativeId(productNativeId);
product.setCostPrice(createProductParam.getCostPrice());
dbclient.createObject(product);
```

I get this error from Objectify:

```
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.app.db.client.model.ProductType' was registered
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Registrar.getMetadataSafe(Registrar.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:53)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.getMetadataSafe(Keys.java:62)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.rawKeyOf(Keys.java:36)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.Keys.keyOf(Keys.java:29)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.Key.create(Key.java:62)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.Ref.create(Ref.java:31)
[INFO]  at com.app.db.client.model.Product.setProductType(Product.java:93)
```

Please help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same Issue and solved as in below steps.

1) Write your own ObjectifyFactoryBean (Just copy from https://github.com/marceloverdijk/objectify-appengine-spring) and update one line in afterPropertiesSet() method.

```
this.objectifyFactory = new ObjectifyFactory();
// Set the factory to ObjectifyService
ObjectifyService.setFactory(objectifyFactory);
```

2) Use this to in spring

```
   <bean id="objectifyFactory" class="com.yourcompany.ObjectifyFactoryBean" >
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.yourcompany.model" />
    </bean>
```

3) Use objectifyFactory in your DAO classes as spring bean.

4) Add the Filter in your web.xml.

```
<!-- ObjectifyFilter filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>objectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>objectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Explanation : I don't know how old version of Objectify work and based on that ObjectifyFactoryBean written, but in latest version of Objectify 5.x it internally use ObjectifyService in Ref operation, which was using the different objectifyFactory instance, So to make it use the same instance of objectifyFactory in whole application, we have set ObjectifyService.setFactory(objectifyFactory) inside our ObjectifyFactoryBean class.

A filter ObjectifyFilter  is also require in web application, because this filter will make call to ObjectifyService.begin() for Objectify session, Normally we call ObjectifyService.begin() only when we do Datastore Operation and but is case of like Ref operation, ObjectifyFilter will do this job for us.

Hope this solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

The spring extension hasn't been updated since 2012 so it's entirely possible that it does not work with current versions of Objectify. I don't know - I would contact the author.

The problem is that your `ProductType` entity has not been registered. Presumably the spring extension is supposed to do that but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Like @stickfigure already mentioned this library hasn't been updated for a long time. That said the Objectify version it depends on - and tested with - is 2.2.x.

However from your logging it seems that the entities have been registered.

To verify if it works with the latest Objectify version you could:

1. clone the lib from https://github.com/marceloverdijk/objectify-appengine-spring
2. update the objectify version
3. run the tests

If that works you at least know the lib works with the latest Objectify version.

Comment: It works fine with entities with simple properties. This problem occurred for Product entity, where it has references (Ref) to other entities.